# Getting "Stack overflow error " while overriding hash-code method

Tags: java, hashcode

Whenever I am trying to print hash-code of class B  I am getting above mentioned errors , please tell what is wrong with my code ?

```
    class B {
        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());    
        //return this.hashCode();
        }   
    }
    public class Testing
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       /*A a = new A(0, null, 1.20);
       A a1 = new A(1,null,1.20);
       A a3 = null;*/
       B b = new B();
       System.out.println(b.hashCode());
       //System.out.println(a.equals(a1));
       //System.out.println(a.equals(a1));
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have an infinite recursion, the `hashCode()` method call itself.

Comment: it is so cool to ask about stack overflow on stackoverflow!

Comment: Do you mean `System.out.println(super.hashCode());`? (Also, this doesn't compile because you're not returning a value).

Comment: can you tell me how can I override it without infinite recursion?

Comment: @RamChowdary easy: don't call `this.hashCode()` in your implementation of `hashCode`.

Comment: why do you want to override the method?

Comment: your function is calling itself, as Titus mentioned... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RamChowdary You probably want to call `super.hashCode()` instead of `this.hashCode()`, don't you?

Comment: Thank you guys for positive replays actually  I doing some R& D on hash code and equals methods , there is no specific requirement . I wanted to override current class hash-code and want to print that one in console

Answer (score 4):

You're creating infinite recursion calling `hashCode` inside hashCode:

```
class B {
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){//<----------------------┐
    //                                             │ this path is infinite                  
    System.out.println(this.hashCode()); //   <----┘
    //return this.hashCode();
    }   
}
```

---

To avoid this:

1. Do not call `hashCode` inside itself.
2. Call superclass `hashcode`  
   **NOTE:** if, as in this case, `class` does not have a direct inheritance, it will always call `Object` hashCode method.

or

3. code it by yourself. 
   **NOTE:** to `override` and create a valid `hashCode` method, you need at least one field in `B` class.

   ```
   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
       // code it, or better, make your IDE code it for you
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is an endless recursion, therefore you get the `StackOverflowError`. 
What you really want to do is probably.

```
class B {
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println(super.hashCode());    
        //return super.hashCode();
    }   
}
```

If you want to override your implementation and print the value you should do it for example like this.

```
class B {
    private Long id = Long.valueOf(0L);
    private String name = "";

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        final int hashCode = 17 * id.hashCode() + 31 * name.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hashCode);    
        return hashCode;
    }   
}
```

Or if you simply want to print it then do nothing in the `hashCode` body.

```
class B {}

public class Testing
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.hashCode());
   }
}
```

Comment: Now which class hash-code I will get here super class hash-code ?

Comment: Yes, you will because you have no other implementation than the super class' `hashCode`. If you want to override the implementation then you have to provide it.

Comment: My intention was I have to print current class override hash code value in console .

Comment: @RamChowdary But you do not have the current override hash as long as you do not implement it. See my updated answer.

Comment: `java.util.Objects.hash(id, name)` is preferable to magic numbers like 17 and 31.

Comment: @jagger yes I want same out put, Thank you buddy.!!

Comment: Happy to have helped, you old chap. If you are happy with the answer then please accept it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the hint. I have not known about this method. This will make my life easier when it comes to Checkstyle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not call this.hashCode() from hashCode() method. it seems that recursive function, which will take you to Stack over flow error.